# Product of 2 numbers equals sum of numbers between them

Tags: performance, ruby

[Problem](http://www.codewars.com/kata/is-my-friend-cheating/javascript):

> Find all the pairs (a, b) whose product is equal to the sum of all numbers in the sequence [1..n] excluding both a and b.

I have made code for one program and need refactoring for code to get execution in less time. I am currently getting 13 sec for 500 number range.

```
def get_correct_array(n)
 beginning_time = Time.now
 puts " Begin with #{Time.now}"
 mul = 0
 arr = []
 last_arr = []

(1..n).each do |x|

 (x+1..n).each do |y|

    mul = x * y
    result = (1..n).reject {|n| n == x || n == y}.inject(&:+)
    if result == mul
        arr.concat([x,y])
        @x = x
        @y = y
    end
 end
end

last_arr << arr

if arr != []
 last_arr << (@x,@y = @y,@x)
end
if arr == []
 []
end

end_time = Time.now
puts " Ended with #{Time.now}"
puts "Time Elapsed -> #{(end_time - beginning_time)}"
p last_arr
end
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! I edited  the title of your question to say something about what the code does, as we all want to improve our code on this site. I hope you get some good answers.

Comment: Can you please indent that code?

Answer (score 2):

Some notes:

- Use 2 spaces for indentation.
- `mul = 0` No need to define variables in Ruby.
- `@x = x`. `@name` is a instance variable, but there is no class here. Use only local variables.
- `(1..n).reject {|n| n == x || n == y}.inject(&:+)`. That's very slow, you should pre-compute the sum before, and just subtract the two elements in every loop.
- `last_arr << (@x,@y = @y,@x)`. Only the last pair is reversed?
- Make functions/methods return something.
- You can use the simple formula `n * (n + 1) / 2` for the sum of (1..n).
- Your code is very, very imperative. For mathematical problems (if not for all), favor a functional style (immutable data-structures)

I'd write:

```
def get_pairs(n)
  range_sum = (n * (n + 1)) / 2
  pairs = (1..n).to_a.combination(2)
  matching_pairs = pairs.select { |x, y| x * y == range_sum - x - y }
  matching_pairs.flat_map { |x, y| [[x, y], [y, x]] }
end

p get_pairs(26) #=> [[15, 21], [21, 15]]
```

With `n = 500` it takes ~0.1s in my machine. If this is not still fast enough, you can still filter out pair values on the range that are too small to possibly match the sum range.

Answer (score 2):

### Code:

I would say that this problem is more mathematical in nature than it is about improvements in code, but here goes:

```
def get_pairs(n)
  sum = (1..n).reduce(:+)
  pairs = ((n / 2)..n).map do |i|
    num = ((sum - i) / i) - 1
    [i, num] if i * num == sum - i - num
  end.compact
  pairs.flat_map { |x, y| [[x, y], [y, x]] }.sort
end
```

I took the time to solve the problem on Codewars and what I figured out is that we needed to reduce the number of combinations that we're looping through. It was just too many to try and go through every single combination.

I managed to achieve that by putting this code together:

```
pairs = ((n / 2)..n).map do |i|
  num = ((sum - i) / i) - 1
  [i, num] if i * num == sum - i - num
end.compact
```

First I start the loop from `(n / 2)` because the numbers needed to multiply and equal the sum of all numbers will not be smaller than half the number given.

I then subtract `i` from the sum with `(sum - i)` and divide it by `i`. This gets us close to a possible multiple, but not the exact multiple. We subtract this number by 1 to get to a number that could possibly fit the requirements.

Once we have 2 potential candidates, we return them if they fit the requirement:

```
i * num == sum - i - num
```

### Explanation:

Let's go through an example to make it clearer:

We'll make `n = 110`. The correct multiples are `70` and `85`.

```
sum = (1..n).reduce(:+)
# 6105
```

So the loop will go from 55 to 110:

```
pairs = ((110 / 2)..110).map do |i|
```

When it gets to 70 it will do:

```
num = ((6105 - 70) / 70) - 1
# 6105 - 70 = 6035
# 6035 / 70 = 86
# 86 - 1 = 85
```

Then we check it:

```
[70, 85] if 70 * 85 == 6105 - 70 - 85
# 70 * 85 = 5950
# 6105 - 70 - 85 = 5950
# 5950 == 5950
# true
```

This will then return:

```
[nil, nil, [70, 85], nil, etc.]
```

With compact we reduce it to:

```
[[70, 85]]
```

Use of flat_map turns this into:

```
[[70, 85], [85, 70]]
```

The math here is the most important aspect. We just had to find a way to reduce the number of combinations to loop through, which this does. Before I got to this solution I was stuck at the 6000ms wall.

### Benchmarks:

For the number `1000003`, my code takes `0.136174` seconds.

I also tested this number with the code in the other answer, but after a few minutes of waiting I terminated it.

This should be a considerably faster solution, but as I said above it is more so a mathematical issue, and not so much a question of efficient code. The code is just to implement the mathematical process after it is found.

Answer (score 2):

As the other posts mention this is a mathematical problem.
To pass the challenge on Codewars it is necessary to reduce this from an \$\mathcal{O}(n^2)\$ when using a brute force method to an \$\mathcal{O}(n)\$ complexity.

The requirement that \$a * b = sum - (a+b)\$ would necessitate that for a given value of b and sum, \$a = \frac{\text{sum} - b}{b + 1}\$ by rearranging the equation above. Where sum = sum of all values in the sequence 1 to n.

With that in mind, we will be able to obtain the results in a single loop from 1 to n.

The following is my solution in php but it can be easily implemented in ruby as it contains minimal php functions.

```
function removeNb($n) {
  $result= [];
  $sum = $n * ($n + 1) / 2;
  for($i = 1; $i<=$n; $i++) {
    //sum = a * b + a + b --- This must be true to meet constraint of product ab equal to sum of all num from 1 to n excluding a and b
    //a = (sum - b) / (b + 1)
    $a = ($sum - $i) / (1+$i);
    if(is_integer($a) && $a < $n) { // a always has a value, ensure that it is an integer less than n as required by kata
      $result[] = [$i, $a];
    }    
  }  

  usort($result, 'sort_by_first');
  return $result;
}

function sort_by_first($a,$b) {
  if($a[0] < $b[0]) return -1;
  if($a[0] > $b[0]) return 1;
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Implementation in Ruby. Complexity is \$\mathcal{O}(n)\$.

```
def removNb(n)
    ans = []
    sum = n*(n+1)/2
    (1..n).each {|i| ((sum-i)%(i+1)==0 and (j=(sum-i)/(i+1))<=n) ? ans<<[i,j] : false}
    ans
end
```

*Sample test cases*

1. Test.assert_equals(removNb(26), [[15, 21], [21, 15]])
2. Test.assert_equals(removNb(102), [[70, 73], [73, 70]])